# Exception: ERROR: Unrecognized fix style 'shake' is part of the RIGID package which is not enabled in this LAM

Tags: google-colaboratory, lammps

I'm trying to run a `LAMMPS` script in a `Colab` environment. However, whenever I try to use the `fix` command with arguments from the `RIGID` package the console gives me the same error.

I tested different installation and build methods, such as through `apt` repository and `CMAKE`:

`Method 1`

```
    !add-apt-repository -y ppa:gladky-anton/lammps
    !add-apt-repository -y ppa:openkim/latest
    !apt update
    !apt install -y lammps-stable
```

`Method 2`

```
    !apt install -y cmake build-essential git ccache
    !rm -rf lammps
    !git clone -b release https://github.com/lammps/lammps.git mylammps

    !rm -rf build
    !mkdir build
    !apt install -y fftw3
    !cd build; cmake ../mylammps/cmake/presets/most.cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr \
    -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=on\
    -D PKG_GPU=on -D GPU_API=cuda -D LAMMPS_EXCEPTIONS=on -D PKG_BODY=on\
    -D PKG_KSPACE=on -D PKG_MOLECULE=on -D PKG_MANYBODY=on -D PKG_ASPHERE=on\
    -D PKG_EXTRA-MOLECULE=on -D PKG_KSPACE=on -D PKG_CG-DNA=on -D PKG_ATC=on\
    -D PKG_ EXTRA-FIX=on -D PKG_FIX=on\
    -D PKG_RIGID=on -D PKG_POEMS=on -D PKG_MACHDYN=on -D PKG_DPD-SMOOTH=on\
    -D PKG_PYTHON=on ../mylammps/cmake
    !cd build; make -j 2
    !cd build; make install; make install-python
```

I also tested it by calling an `external script` using the `file()` method and writing commands to `LAMMPS` using the `command()` method.

The part of my `code` in the `python` script that returns an error is::

```
    !pip install --user mpi4py
    #!pip install lammps-cython
```

```py
    from mpi4py import MPI
    from lammps import lammps
    #from lammps import PyLammps
    #from lammps import Lammps
    import glob
    from google.colab import files
    from google.colab import drive
    L = lammps()
```

...

```py
    L.command("fix            freeze teflon setforce 0.0 0.0 0.0")
    L.command("fix            fSHAKE water shake 0.0001 10 0 b 1 a 1")
    L.command("fix            fRIGID RIG rigid molecule")
```

Or the same rows in LAMMPS script called:

```
    #Using an external script
    !pip install --user mpi4py
    #!pip install lammps-cython
```

```py
    from mpi4py import MPI
    from lammps import lammps
    #from lammps import PyLammps
    #from lammps import Lammps
    import glob
    from google.colab import files
    from google.colab import drive
    L = lammps()
```

...

```py
    L.file(input[0])
    me = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
    nprocs = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()
    print("Proc %d out of %d procs has" % (me,nprocs),L)
    MPI.Finalize()
```

The output error is:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-60-a968719e9bc6> in <module>()
          1 L = lammps()
    ----> 2 L.file(input[0])
          3 me = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
          4 nprocs = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()
          5 print("Proc %d out of %d procs has" % (me,nprocs),L)
    
    1 frames
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lammps/core.py in file(self, path)
        559 
        560     with ExceptionCheck(self):
    --> 561       self.lib.lammps_file(self.lmp, path)
        562 
        563   # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lammps/core.py in __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
         47   def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
         48     if self.lmp.has_exceptions and self.lmp.lib.lammps_has_error(self.lmp.lmp):
    ---> 49       raise self.lmp._lammps_exception
         50 
         51 # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    Exception: ERROR: Unrecognized fix style 'shake' is part of the RIGID package which is not enabled in this LAM
```

Any suggestions what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the RIGID package. For better flexibility on LAMMPS features it is better to build it from source code:

Download the latest **stable** version, and change the directory into it

```
git clone -b stable https://github.com/lammps/lammps.git mylammps
cd mylammps/src
```

Inclued all packes you need, obviously you need RIGID to use *fix shake*

```
make yes-rigid
```

Now you will need to build using MPI and share its library. This may take a while, you can add '-j N' flag to do it in parallel with N cores, I do it with 8

```
make mpi mode=shlib -j 8
```

Finally install Pylammps

```
make install-python
```

Now you should be able to use PyLammps through Colab successfully.